# Firebase - can't set title and message of notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

From my PHP server I sent this notification data to Firebase API:

```
$fields = [
    'to' => "fcm....",
    'notification' => [
        'title' => 'Test Test Test',
        'body' => 'MSG MSG MSG'
    ],
    'data' => [
        'type' => 'message',
        'sender' => 'someone'
    ],
    'priority' => 'high'
];
```

In android studio, this is the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class that extends the `FirebaseMessagingService` class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification("Test", "Test");
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificatino)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

The problem is I keep get notifications with the title and message from the server (Title Title Title, MSG MSG MSG) instead of get notifications with the title and message I have passed to `sendNotification` as arguments:

[image: The notification I receive not including the title and message I have passed to the function]

Answer (score 0):

Did you added `MyFirebaseMessagingService` into to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file like so:

```
<service android:name=".firebase.messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also, take in consideration that if the app is closed (killed or inactive) the class wont be called and you will need to send the message data properly from the server.

Comment: Maybe try to debug it - it might help understand what the problem is.  add a breakpoint in the "MyFirebaseMessagingService" class to see if it get there at all.

Comment: I it is get there, I write "Log.i("Notification", "Notification")" and it displays it.